# JTable won't repaint/refresh on data insert into mysql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I get data from MySQL db and populate the JTable with DefaultTableModel. Then I show it on screen. After data is added from textboxes into the db, JTable wont refresh. I've checked the db and inserted data is there. I've tried with `table.repaint()` or `dTableModel.fireTableDataChanged()` in event listener for add button and still nothing. Here is the code:

```
public class DbTable {

    private JLabel lFirstName, lLastName, lState, lBirthDate;
    private JTextField fFirstName, tLastName, tState, tBirthDate;
    private JButton btnAdd;
    private Object[][] databaseResults;
    private Object[] columns = { "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4",
            "Col 5", "ЈCol 6", "Col 7" };
    private ResultSet rows;
    private ResultSet rowsCb;

    private JComboBox combobox;


    private DefaultTableModel dTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
            databaseResults, columns) {
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            Class returnValue; 

            if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
                returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            } else { 
                returnValue = Object.class;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    };

    private JTable table = new JTable(dTableModel);
    Connection conn = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DbTable dbTable = new DbTable();

        dbTable.getTable();
    }

    public void getTable() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database", "root", "");

            Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement(
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            String selectStuff = "SELECT  `invoice`.`id` ,  `client`, `date`, `project`, `amount`,`unitPrice`, `total`"
                    + "FROM  `invoice` ,  `clients`"
                    + "WHERE  `invoice`.`clientID` =  `clients`.`id`"
                    + "ORDER BY  `invoice`.`id` ASC ";

            rows = sqlState.executeQuery(selectStuff);

            Object[] tempRow;

            while (rows.next()) {
                tempRow = new Object[] { rows.getInt(1), rows.getString(2),
                        rows.getString(3), rows.getString(4), rows.getInt(5),
                        rows.getInt(6), rows.getDouble(7) };
                dTableModel.addRow(tempRow);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        // frame.add(combobox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // Define values for my labels
        lFirstName = new JLabel("Klijent ID: ");
        lLastName = new JLabel("Datum: ");
        lState = new JLabel("Projekat: ");
        lBirthDate = new JLabel("Ukupno"); // Define the size of text fields
        fFirstName = new JTextField(10);
        tLastName = new JTextField(10);
        tBirthDate = new JTextField(10);
        tState = new JTextField(10);
        btnAdd = new JButton("Add");

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String sDatum = "", sProjekat = "";
                int sKlijenId;
                double sUkupno = 0.00;
                sKlijenId = Integer.parseInt(fFirstName.getText());
                sDatum = tLastName.getText();
                sProjekat = tState.getText();
                sUkupno = Double.parseDouble(tBirthDate.getText());

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sjajplusz", "root", "");

                    Statement sqlState = conn.createStatement(
                            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

                    String selectStuff = "SELECT * FROM invoice";

                    rows = sqlState.executeQuery(selectStuff);

                    rows.moveToInsertRow();
                    rows.updateInt("clientID", sKlijenId);
                    rows.updateString("date", sDatum);
                    rows.updateString("project", sProjekat);
                    rows.updateDouble("total", sUkupno);

                    rows.insertRow();
                    rows.updateRow();

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.getMessage();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int invoiceId = 0;

                try {
                    rows.last();
                    invoiceId = rows.getInt(1);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }


//              Object[] invoice = {invoiceId, sKlijenId, sDatum, sProjekat, "", "", sUkupno};
//              
//              dTableModel.addRow(invoice);

                dTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();

            }
        });

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(); // Put components in the panel
        inputPanel.add(lFirstName);
        inputPanel.add(fFirstName);
        inputPanel.add(lLastName);
        inputPanel.add(tLastName);
        inputPanel.add(lState);
        inputPanel.add(tState);
        inputPanel.add(lBirthDate);
        inputPanel.add(tBirthDate);
        inputPanel.add(btnAdd);

        frame.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this is follow up on this youtube series [Java JTable 38](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-zAbYs9J7w)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not reloading the data from the database. After you have added it to the database you have to reload the data, refresh your `DefaultTableModel` and then call `fireTableDataChanged()`. You are doing this only initially in your `getTable()` method. You have to extract that code which loads your data and call it in your action listener.

Btw. your code is not very well organized even the way you are inserting the data is a bit complicated. I would suggest to take some basic tutorials about this.

Comment: The code is just a follow up from the yt tutorial series. How do I refresh `DefaultTableModel`?

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` provides the method `setDataVector()` where you can pass your new data.

Comment: ok so I've got it to work like this:

`dTableModel.setNumRows(0);
table.setModel(dTableModel);
table.setModel(getData());
`

and than `getData()` is separate method that grabs fresh data from db.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If it works your question seems to be answered. There might be a better way but for now it's important that you understand every single code line you wrote to understand the concepts behind JTable and TableModel.

Comment: -1, ` refresh your DefaultTableModel and then call fireTableDataChanged().` - invoking any of the fireXXX() methods should be done by the TableModel, not the application code. The DefaultTableModel does invoke the appropriate method.

Comment: @LordZed, why are you invoking the setModel() method twice, and why are you setting the number of rows to 0 if you plan on replacing the entire model. Just invoke the setModel(...) method once with the data you want displayed.

Comment: @camickr I think architectural concerns are out of scope here. The OP is using a DefaultTableModel not an own implementation.

Comment: `The OP is using a DefaultTableModel` - exactly, there is no need to invoke fireTableDataChanged, since the DefaultTableModel already does that.

Comment: @camick `dTableModel = getData();` just appends data to existing data in `JTable`. That's why I set `dTableModel.setNumRows(0)` before table model gets new data. And please feel free to refer me to addition literature for OOP, or if you have suggestions how to improve existing code, let me know as well.